# showing the calculated percentage on Progressbar

Tags: android

Hi I want to develop financial application i have taken total salary and amount spent ie. transport,internet,electricity bill so on..... I have taken values and added and calculated percentage also but I am unable to show the calculated percentage in progress bar.

```
int total = (amount1+amount2+amount3+amount4+amount5);
double final1=((double)total/amount)*100;
```

Here `final1` is the calculated percentage now this percentage should be represented in 
Progressbar

```
ProgressBar progressbar1 = new ProgressBar(this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
progressbar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
progressbar1.setPadding(20, 10, 10, 10);
progressbar1.setScrollBarStyle(ProgressBar.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);
progressbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressbar1.setProgress(0);
progressbar1.setMax(100);
progressbar1.incrementProgressBy(FINAL1);
```

Here `final1` is in double we need convert it into integer because the below statement will accept only integer

```
int a = (int)FINAL1;
int b = (int)Math.round(a);

progressbar1.incrementProgressBy(b);
```

Please help me I am stuck with this from last 4 days

Comment: Please, edit the question into proper case (not all caps), then we can look at your problem!!!

Comment: Ok, now it's not killing our eyes anymore. Thank code for http://www.convertcase.net/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick searching for "android progressbar example" points us to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).
It shows that you can use `progressBar.setProgress(int progress)`.

The `progress` variable should be betwee ProgressBar's minimum and maximum (`setMax()`).

If you show progress from 0 to 100, and your *total* is 100, and your *value* or *final1* is for example 33, it will set to 33%.

So either change progressBar's maximum to your *total*, or normalize the value between progressbar's min and max properties.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted by using the tick box, thanks